# How to concat a specific number to existing values for a particular column for all rows

Tags: mysql, sql

For Example there is a table `Student` and a column `Student_ID` and which contains value like `1` , `2` , `3` .. I just want to add `00` in front of these numbers and I want to perform this using a single query.

Comment: have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Yes i am newbie in sql and i am able to do it for a particular row.

Comment: then show some sample data and your attempt

Comment: What do you want in front of 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unlikely that this will work, if your `Student_ID` is an `int` type (which is common practice for primary ID of a table).  The reason is this:  Non-zero integers never begin with 0.  The 0 will be dropped. If you want to concatenate any integer other than a 0, you would:

```
UPDATE Student SET Student_ID = CONCAT('11', Student_ID);
```

If you insist on using `0`'s, then I think you must change the datatype to a `varchar` or other non-integer data type.

If you change it to `varchar`, the above statement should work, just change `11` to `00`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think you're confusing data storage and data display

Comment: Thanks a Bunch! found my mistake. i was using the exact query but on int data type. Thanks Again